# Push key and value into associative array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session, associative-array

I want to push data and key into associative array.
I fetch from database something like this  -->

```
 $data=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id,name FROM names ");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_Assoc($data)){
       $id[] = $row['id'];
       $name[] = $row['name'];
 }
```

if this fethes something like this ->

***$id = {2,4,8,20} and $name={'David','Goliath','ronaldo','messi'}***

i want an array like this

```
$_SESSION['list'] = array(
 'David' => 2,
 'Goliath' => 4,
  'ronaldo'  =>8,
  'messi' => 20
);
```

how will i push those values in an array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$result = array();
$data=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id,name FROM names ");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_Assoc($data)){
       $result[$row['name']] = $row['id'];
}

$_SESSION['list'] = $result;
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple.

```
 $_SESSION['list'] = array();

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_Assoc($data)){
    $_SESSION['list'][$row['name']] = $row['id'];
 }
```